# MKMapView is not initialized

Tags: ios, unit-testing, mapkit

I am doing some unit tests on a ViewController that has an MKMapView.

If I want to test if the mapview is not nil, I have to explicitly initialize it, which is unnecessary to otherwise just use the mapview.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface HomeVC : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {

  MKMapView* mapView;
  CLLocationManager* locationManager;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;
@property(nonatomic, strong)CLLocationManager* locationManager;
@property(nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation;
@end 

@implementation HomeVC
@synthesize mapView, cameraButton,cameraView, locationManager, currentLocation;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];   
  self.mapView = MKMapView.new;
  self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
}
```

If I put a breakpoint after the map initialization, it shows the mapView initialized with only a UIView property. It is properly hooked up in my Storyboard file. And works fine, I just can't test any properties on it.

Comment: try replacing self.mapView = MKMapView.new; with self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];

Comment: @user2277872 .new is ugly but that shouldn't be a problem... (nonetheless he should what you proposed!)

Comment: well isn't .new just used for mostly creating a new object of it instead of creating a place in memory for it to be used?

Comment: .new is just an alias for alloc init. I can even just comment it out. It doesn't need to be initialized unless I want to check if the map isn't nil.